# Use var from Ajax success into another Ajax Success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have 2 Ajax call, one of them in the success i want to save the data in a var to use into another ajax call.

```
  $.ajax({
      all my options
      } ),
      success: function(data){
        jsondata = $(data).get(0);
        var tempVal = jsondata.valor_variable; <-------------//- this var
      }
  });

  $.ajax({
      all my options
      } ),
      success: function(data){
        $('.content-' + value).load("Views/temp", function(){
          $('#temp').text(tempVal); <----------------------//- use it here
        })
      }
  });
```

how could I do that?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki there's an alternative way to do that? i just need to save that data to reuse it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the second request in a separated function and call it in the success callback of the first request by passing the variable you want `tempVal` :

```
$.ajax({
  all my options
  } ),
  success: function(data){
    jsondata = $(data).get(0);
    var tempVal = jsondata.valor_variable; <-------------//- this var

    second_ajax_request(tempVal);
  }
});

fucntion second_ajax_request(tempVal){
    $.ajax({
      all my options
      } ),
      success: function(data){
        $('.content-' + value).load("Views/temp", function(){
          $('#temp').text(tempVal); <----------------------//- use it here
        })
      }
    });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I'd set it up like this,

```
$.ajax({
  all my options
  } ),
  success: function(data){
    jsondata = $(data).get(0);
    var tempVal = jsondata.valor_variable; <-------------//- this var

    $.ajax({
      all my options
      } ),
      success: function(data){
        $('.content-' + value).load("Views/temp", function(){
          $('#temp').text(tempVal);
        })
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use deferred. Then your calls will be chained.
https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/